# Filter each subdomain in list based on unique value

Tags: shell, awk, grep

i have two lists or urls
first `listofdomains.txt` contains as following

```
http://example.com
https://www.example.com
https://abc-test.example.com
```

second `urls_params.txt` contains as following

```
http://example.com/?param1=123
http://example.com/?param1=123&param2=456
https://www.example.com/?param1=123
https://www.example.com/?param1=123&param2=456
https://abc-test.example.com/?param1=123
https://abc-test.example.com/?param1=123&param2=456
```

i need to loop between two lists to grep from `urls_params.txt` all urls belong to every subdomains and save it with subdomain name.txt

for example the desired output would be
file named `example.com` and contains

```
http://example.com/?param1=123
http://example.com/?param1=123&param2=456
```

and so on for the rest of subdomains

my solution which is did not work is filter `listofdomains.txt` list to be only as

```
example.com
www.example.com
abc-test.example.com
```

and save it in file named `list`
then executing following command
`while read -r url; do $(cat urls_params.txt | awk -v u="$url" '{print u}') ; done < list`

BUT the output is error

```
example.com: command not found
www.example.com: command not found
abc-test.example.com: command not found
```

Thanks

Comment: The command substitution `$(...)` arounl the command is useless, just take it out. Oh, and lose the [useless `cat`.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Input (from the question):**

```
$ ls
listofdomains.txt  tst.awk  urls_params.txt
```

**Script:**

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    dom = $0
    sub("https?://","",dom)
    sub("/.*","",dom)
}
NR==FNR {
    dom2urls[dom] = dom2urls[dom] $0 ORS
    next
}
dom != prev {
    close(out)
    out = dir "/" dom
    prev = dom
}
{ printf "%s", dom2urls[dom] > out }
```

**Execute it:**

```
$ awk -v dir="$PWD" -f tst.awk urls_params.txt listofdomains.txt
```

**Output:**

```
$ ls
abc-test.example.com  example.com  listofdomains.txt  tst.awk  urls_params.txt  www.example.com
```

```
$ head *.com
==> abc-test.example.com <==
https://abc-test.example.com/?param1=123
https://abc-test.example.com/?param1=123&param2=456

==> example.com <==
http://example.com/?param1=123
http://example.com/?param1=123&param2=456

==> www.example.com <==
https://www.example.com/?param1=123
https://www.example.com/?param1=123&param2=456
```

You don't actually need `listofdomains.txt` unless there some domains you want to exclude from the output or some domains not included in `urls_params.txt` that you want to get empty output files for.

If you only want output files created for domains that have entries in the `urls_params.txt` file (i.e. no empty output files) then just change:

```
{ printf "%s", dom2urls[dom] > out }
```

to:

```
dom in dom2urls { printf "%s", dom2urls[dom] > out }
```

Comment: Thx @Ed this was really helpful,
last thing, i`m using this inside bash script and i have a global variable for specific directory location how should this will define inside awk script?
in another word i need to do following ```awk -f tst.awk urls_params.txt listofdomains.txt output_dir/```

Comment: I updated my answer. just change `-v dir="$PWD"` to `-v dir="whatever_you_want"`

Comment: Thanks Ed, appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

found it

`while  read -r url ; do cat urls_params.txt | grep -E "$url" | tee $url.txt ; done  < list`

Comment: Don't do that, it's the wrong approach. If you copy/paste that into http://shellcheck.net it'll tell you about some of the problems with it. You can read about others at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice/

Comment: @EdMorton the link changed my thoughts about rebuilding my shell scripts with less noisy, consuming way as it is right now, really thx for providing that.
one more time awk came to solve an issue professionally

Comment: @EdMorton one more thing the solution provided it also created files for domains even if it haven`t urls inside `urls_params.txt` . How to avoid that??

Comment: I assume you're asking about my answer so I edited that to answer your question. If you have any other questions about my answer then please post them as comments under my answer.